# How to represent website as a fixed size vector?

Tags: neural-networks, internet

Generally speaking, how to transform a hierarchical tree structure into a fixed size vector?

I have a **set (tens of thousands) of websites** as my input data. Each website is **represented by HTML structure** (tree).

And for my experiments, I **need to represent those websites as a fixed size vector**, i.e. each vector corresponding to a website has the same length.

The experiments are focused on the general structure of the websites so we can omit texts and contents of paragraphs and use only the hierarchical structure of website elements.

There are several issues, one of them is the variable depth and size of the tree (hierarchical tree specifying the structure of the document). Thus the transformation from a website to a vector does not necessarily have to be lossless (e.g. we can cut the elements that are really deep in the structure).

To wrap it up:

**Input:**

Set of tens of thousands of websites like this (without texts, only tags, attributes etc.)

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Desired output:**

Set of vectors (of the same size) like the following (it's just an example, not based on anything real):

```
(1, 13, 0, 1.4, ..., 9, 11) 
(21, 0, 9, 0.3, ..., 1, 10.43)
```

**Reason/aim:**

I need to use the "website" as a input to a neural network.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bag-of-words model, with each html tag represented as a word. Another useful representation could be some sort of 'histogram', where you track the absolute or relative frecuency of html tags. They are both built around the same concept.